# How do I present a Menu from a button tap in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

Is there a SwiftUI equivalent to "showsMenuAsPrimaryAction" in UIKit?

Edit: iOS 14 Beta 3 introduces Menu

```
Menu("Options") {
Button("Option 1", action: actionOne)
Button("Option 2", action: actionTwo)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is nothing equivalent to UIMenu's showsMenuAsPrimaryAction in SwiftUI

You can display SwiftUI context menus with a long press, and there's no other SwiftUI UIMenu equivalent. You can use UIMenu inside the Context menu(https://www.raywenderlich.com/6328155-context-menus-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started).

Alternatively, you can present a List on button click that can simulate the UIMenu actions.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I'll update for others when we get an equivalency.